# Using ajaxcomplete in D7 to parse links

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am using two themes, one which is Mobile jQuery based that is presented to any mobile user. Also, I am using a jQuery lightbox module that is enabled for visitors on the desktop site to view a gallery of images in a lightbox. Going back to the mobile theme, I have a javascript file containing some jQuery logic to strip out certain attributes from my links as a result of the lightbox module. I would like to disable lightbox module for this theme, but I have no idea on how to do it.

To counter the effects of this module, I am writing the following function. The purpose of it is to parse every link, and if that link's 'href' attribute ends with jpg, png, gif, or pdf, I change that link's 'ajax-data' or 'rel' attributes. The following is my code.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.my_theme = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

        $('a').ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
            if ($(this).attr('href').match(/[.](jpg|png|gif)$/)) {
                $(this).attr('ajax-data', 'false');
            } else if ($(this).attr('href').match(/[.](pdf)$/)) {
                $(this).attr('rel', 'external');
            }
         });
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This code does not necessarily work, but the following does. However, the following only works on page load, and not after a page has been loaded via ajax:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.my_theme = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            // Automatically discover document links and apply the following attribute.
            $('a[href]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('href').match(/[.](jpg|png|pdf)$/)) {
                    $(this).attr('ajax-data', 'false');
                }
            });
            alert('success');
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```